# How to delay (e.g. 1s) the showing of a loading indicator in React Redux Saga App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using reducer to check various action status like success, pending, error etc. I want to display loading indicator after a delay of 1s. If the response comes before 1s, then I do not want to show the loading indicator.

Currently, I am not updating the loading state on pending status but firing an action from render function with a setTimeout.

This creates a problem when response is delivered before Timeout period. How can I resolve this problem?

reducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
  error: false,
  loading: false,
  showModal: false,
};

export default function appReducer(state=initialState, action) {

  if (action.type.endsWith('ERROR'))
    return {
      ...state,
      error: true,
      loading: false,
      showModal: true,
    };
  else if (action.type.endsWith('PENDING'))
    return {
      ...state,
      error: false,
      loading: false,
    };
  else if (action.type.endsWith('SUCCESS'))
      return {
        ...state,
        error: false,
        loading: false,
      };
  else if (action.type === errorModalActionTypes.CLOSE_MODAL.ACTION)
    return {
      ...state,
      showModal: false,
    };
  else if (action.type === loadingIndicatorActionTypes.UPDATE_LOADING.ACTION)
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: true,
    };
  else
    return state;
}
```

saga.js

```
export function* getCollections(action) {
  try {
    yield put({ type: GET_COLLECTIONS.PENDING });
    const collections = yield call(getCollectionsAPI);
    yield put({ type: GET_COLLECTIONS.SUCCESS, collections });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: GET_COLLECTIONS.ERROR, error });
  }
}

// These are the watchers that trigger the start of a saga

export default function* saga() {
  yield fork(takeEvery, GET_COLLECTIONS.ACTION, getCollections);
}
```

LoadingIndicator.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { isLoading, hasError } from './selectors';
import { updateLoading } from './actions';
import LoadingIndicatorComponent  from '../../../../components/loadingIndicator';
import './loadingIndicator.css';

export class LoadingIndicator extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log('called');
    const { loading, error } = this.props;

    if (!error)
      setTimeout(this.props.updateLoading, 1000);

    return (
      <div className={`${loading && !error ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`}>
        <LoadingIndicatorComponent>
          Loading...
        </LoadingIndicatorComponent>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loading: isLoading(state),
  error: hasError(state),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateLoading })(LoadingIndicator);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your architecture, what I would suggest is this:

```
export class LoadingIndicator extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.timeoutID = null;
    this.state = {
      showIndicator: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ensureTimer(this.props);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.destroyTimer();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if (props.loading !== this.props.loading || props.error !== this.props.error) {
      this.ensureTimer(props);
    }
  }

  ensureTimer(props) {
    if (props.loading && !props.error) {
      if (!this.timeoutID) {
        this.timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
          this.timeoutID = null;
          this.setState({showIndicator: true });
        }, 1000);
      }
    } else {
      this.destroyTimer();
    }
  }

  destroyTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutID);
    this.timeoutID = null;
    this.setState({showIndicator: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, error } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={`${this.state.showIndicator ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`}>
        <LoadingIndicatorComponent>
          Loading...
        </LoadingIndicatorComponent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loading: isLoading(state),
  error: hasError(state),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateLoading })(LoadingIndicator);
```

There are a few things to note here:

1. If nothing else, please please get out of this answer that `render()` is supposed to be a pure function. It should not alter any state. Instead, given the same props & state, it should return the same thing every time (and without setting side effects)
2. Instead, the choice I made was to use state, via the showIndicator. There's another world where you wrap logic inside the parent container, but this was the simplest way to get the example across.
3. The main logic behind this is as follows: When the component mounts for the first time, or whenever the props change, see if the loading dialog should show up. This is done via a setTimeout that then just updates the showIndicator flag. If the condition no longer holds, then the timer is destroyed, and showIndicator is set to false.
4. I would read up on the other react lifetime hooks to make sure it makes sense as to why you need to listen to all of these various events: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: In point 2, you have mentioned to wrap logic inside the parent container. The current code is of a smart container component which includes "LoadingIndicatorComponent" dumb component. Do you mean to say to include logic in the parent container component of "LoadingIndicator" ? Why would that be helpful?

Comment: Ah, given what you said, then the way the example has been given would be the correct way to do it.